# How to say I love something in german?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, expression

I've noticed that people use ''ich liebe...(jmd)'' for people, a lot, but not for things.

How should I say ''I love Medicine'' or ''I love Africa'' or ''I love New York'', for example?

Like, I mean things or places, not people. I  don't feel that ''gefällt mir'' expresses the love, the passion that one can have for a certain thing.

Can I say, for example, ''Ich liebe Medizin''. Is there another way to express it in german?

Comment: You can use it for things. Why do you have the impression that you can't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such rule. It's just the fact German speakers consider *lieben* as overblown. A white lie, most of the times. And those are abhored in German customs. That aside, you could always say

> Ich liebe Afrika.
>
> Ich liebe das Fach Medizin.

But using *mögen* or *gefallen* is far more common, especially with everyday things:

> Ich mag Kaffee. (NOT: *Ich liebe Kaffee.*)
>
> Mir gefällt ihr Stil. (NOT: *Ich liebe ihren Stil.*)